# Overwrite variable to file in python

Tags: python, file, loops

I defined a function that generates some names and I run from loop:

```
output = open('/tmp/NameGen-output.txt', 'w')
while True:
     var = NameGen(name)
      .
      .
      .
       if sth:
            output.write(var)
       elif other:
            output.write(var)
            break
       else:
            break
output.close()
```

## update:

first iteration ,content of `NameGen-output.txt`:

```
a
b
c
```

second iteration:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

and etc

So if I overwrite it the second iteration would be just:

```
d
e
```

What I am going to ask is:

As you see var equals `NameGen()` and for each iteration content of var is written to `NameGen-output.txt` but I want to overwrite output of  for each iteration of `NameGen()` to `NameGen-output.txt` no appending to it.

Could you possibly help me?

Thank you

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish, can you demonstrate some expected output?

Comment: It is simple: that function generates name in each iteration, and write it to that file. for next iteration it has some repeated names and then append them to file, I want to overwite for each iteration to solve that problem

Comment: Do you use the intermediate file? If you don't (and it doesn't appear like you do) can't you just write after exiting the loop? Keep temporary variables in an array and then `files.writelines(thatarray)`

Comment: Thank you +1 to you comment, but in my case I think it would be better if I don't use arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can truncate the existing file without opening and closing it, and flush to ensure that it is written to:

```
output = open('/tmp/NameGen-output.txt', 'w')
while True:
    var = NameGen()
    .
    .
    .
    if not sth and not other:
         break
    else:
         output.flush()
         output.seek(0)
         output.truncate()
         output.write(var)
         output.flush()
         output.write(var)

         if other:
             break


output.close()
```

Comment: +1 because I think this is what I want. please see my update, and help me. thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could move the file opening (note: using `with` context manager is preferred) inside the loop:

```
while True:
    var = NameGen()
    ...
    with open('/tmp/NameGen-output.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write(var)
    ...
...
```

Comment: My loop has a long duration. Is it make sense to do that?

Comment: @MortezaLSC do you mean it takes a long time to run through one iteration, or it iterates for a long time, or both? It's hard to offer suggestions without more information on what you're using the file to do, exactly.

Comment: @MortezaLSC that hasn't answered my question, or clarified much at all. Why are you using a file? Is file handling a significant proportion of each loop iteration's duration? Is time critical and/or are you currently having problems with how long it takes?

Comment: I think for each iteration I open file and close it doesn't make sense, I want one time open file and when my loop finishes I close it,  Thank you very much(What I said was explanation about long duration of loop , maybe I couldn't first let you know accurately, pardon), I updated again.

Comment: @MortezaLSC you are free to adopt whatever implementation you like, but there's no point asking for advice if you won't provide the information needed; you *still* haven't answered any of the questions in my comments so far, or explained why you don't want to use e.g. lists.

Comment: His hesitation to use lists could be driven by the large size of that possible list. Although I don't know about the inner workings of python I do not think that opening and closing the file over and over would actually do much in slowing down the program, but since its block buffered he doesn't have to save as much to RAM.

Comment: because there would me too many of names and I want to expand my script in order to do as multithread, So this is not good idea for `memory` .. I used file because I am calling that names and doing stuff with that name to other function,I have to write them to file. Thank you `very much` for your god help, +1 I would use it in other scripts surely but the @Antti Haapala's answer is what I want.